# Eager loading categories and assets inside related entries for gallery

Tags: assets, categories, relations, performance, eager-loading

I am looking for some advice on how to best streamline a gallery system on a site, but having trouble wrapping my head around the syntax needed to eager load nested asset fields with categories inside a related entry.  Any help is appreciated!

Structure:

- The "exhibition" section has an "Entries" field named galleryEntry
- That field relates to entries in the "gallery" section.
- The "gallery" section has an "Assets" field called assetGallery that can contain multiple images
- These images have a title and a "category" field called workCategory.

In the /exhibition/_entry template, I'm trying to display a gallery of images with asset thumbnail, asset title, and asset category.  Simplified code:

```
{% if galleryEntry|length %}

    {% set relatedAssets = galleryEntry.assetGallery.all() %}
    
    <div class="gallery">
    
    {% for work in relatedAssets %}
        
        <figure>
        <img class="thumb" src="{{ work.url }}" alt="{{ work.title }}"/>
        <figcaption>
            Title: {{ work.title }} / 
            Category: {{ work.workCategory.one().title}}
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
        
    {% endfor %}
    
    </div>
    
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

A good thing to know about Craft is that all relational fields (such as your Assets field `galleryEntry.assetGallery`, for instance) return [element query](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html) objects. So, all methods and parameters available to element queries are available on that object – including the `with()` param which can be used to eager-load relations contained in said field.

To eager-load the `workCategory` categories for the related assets in the `assetGallery` field, all you'll need to do is add that `with()` parameter to your existing `assetGallery` query:

```
{% set relatedAssets = galleryEntry.assetGallery.with(['workCategory']).all() %}
```

To take it one step further, you can even leverage [nested eager-loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-nested-sets-of-elements) when you first pull the `galleryEntry` entry, which would reduce the number of queries even further. The below example would eager-load both the assets in the gallery entry's `galleryEntry` field *and* the categories in those assets' `workCategory` field (note that the below example assumes you have an exhibition entry set to a `entry` variable, and that the gallery entry is related to that entry via a `galleryEntry` Entries field):

```
{% set galleryEntry = entry.galleryEntry.with(['assetGallery.workCategory']).one() %}
```

(Note that in terms of performance the above is probably not noticeable if there's only ever a single `galleryEntry` – but it can be super effective if you're querying multiple elements, with multiple nested related elements.)

Beyond the above, I recommend looking over [the official docs on eager-loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) - they are pretty detailed and cover most common use cases, including nesting and Matrix fields.